# $(window).load() after Modernizr call... Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, modernizr

**I've this HTML**

```
<head>
<script src="modernizr.js"></script>
<script>
    Modernizr.load([{
        // jQuery
        test: document.getElementsByClassName, // IE>8
        nope: 'js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
        yep: 'js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'
        },{
        test: Modernizr.somefunction,
        load: 'somecode.js'
    }
</script>
</head>
```

**And somecode.js**

```
$(window).load(function(){
   //somecode
});
```

Doesn't work (Sometimes works, sometime doesn't only in Google Chrome).

I couldn't use $(document).ready() too, but could fix it with setTimeout with no seconds(Magic!)

```
$(document)ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      // some code
   });
});
```

Any idea to fix jQuery load method?

Comment: How about not using modernizr to load jquery?

`<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script><![endif]--><!--[if gte IE 9 | !IE ]><!--><script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script><![endif]-->`

Comment: Works only for old IE no all older browsers(like Netscape)

Comment: Seriously? Not even I support this anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, Modernizr works after some little objects load.

**To fix it:**

```
$(document)ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){

      function NewFunction(){
         // some code
         }
      // For Tags action
      if($('selector').find('otherselector').length > 0 ){
          NewFunction();
          }else{
             $('selector').load(function(){
                NewFunction(); 
                 });
              }
        // For Attributes action      
      if((typeof($('selector').attr('attributename')) === 'undefined') || ($('selector').attr('attributename') === null)){
          NewFunction();
          }else{
             $('selector').load(function(){
                NewFunction(); 
                 }); 
              }
        // Width | Height img
        if($('imgselector').height() !== '0px'){
            NewFunction();
          }else{
             $('imgselector').load(function(){
                NewFunction(); 
                 });
              }

   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `complete` callback

```
Modernizr.load([{
        // jQuery
        test: document.getElementsByClassName, // IE>8
        nope: 'js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
        yep: 'js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js',
        complete: function () {
            Modernizr.load('somecode.js');
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's too slow, and sometimes doesn't work.

Comment: It's slow because you should always wait for jQuery to load, your previous solution had race condition, that's why it's worked sometimes.